# Как вытащить определенные значения из бд SQLite (Python)

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

У меня есть код простого телеграм-бота (использую Telebot) на Python 3.9

```
import telebot
import sqlite3

bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')
connection = sqlite3.connect('database.db', check_same_thread=False)
cursor = connection.cursor()

# ответ бота на команду /profile
@bot.message_handler(commands=['profile'])
def command_Profile(message):
    uid = message.from_user.id
    
    UserID = '\nID: ' + str(uid)
    isUserAdmin = 'Администратор: ' # + значение из таблицы (true/false)
    
    profile_message = 'Ваш профиль:\n' + userID + isUserAdmin # текст сообщения, которое отправит бот
    bot.send_message(uid, profile_message)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Также есть база данных (SQLite), где в таблице *users* хранятся значения user_id (int, ID пользователя в телеграме) и isAdmin (bool, является ли пользователь администратором):

| id | user_id | isAdmin |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11111111 | 0 |
| 2 | 22222222 | 1 |

P.S. uid передается в таблицу в user_id, когда пользователь пишет /start. Этот кусок кода здесь не представлен.

У меня вопрос: как можно посмотреть, является ли пользователь администратором и как добавить полученное значение в isUserAdmin?

Впервые работаю с субд, буду благодарен любой помощи

Comment: `user_id` это айди пользователя в телеграм?

Comment: Да, uid передается в таблицу в user_id, когда пользователь пишет /start. Этот кусок кода здесь не представлен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def get_db(uid):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
    user = conn.execute(f'SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id ={uid}').fetchone()

    if user is None:
        conn.close()
        return None
    else:
        conn.close()
        row = user[0]
        user_id = user[1]
        is_adm = user[2]
        return row, user_id, is_adm


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    row, user_id, is_adm = get_db(message.chat.id)
    if is_adm:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Администратор: {user_id}')
```

выполняете запрос к БД - `SELECT` [почитать](https://proglib.io/p/sql-for-20-minutes).

в моём примере запрашиваются все данные имеющиеся в таблице `users` с условием (`where`) поиска по `uid`, после извлечения получается кортеж (`tuple`) с данными, обратится к элементу можно по индексу.

ну а дальше либо возвращаете все данные, либо те что требуются и применяете их там где нужно.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Ваш пример очень помог разобраться.